# How to skip wait in "Rerun from specific activity" in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline with "Until" activity, and in the "Until" activity it will have the "Wait" activity and check status activity. The Until will exist only when check is done, otherwise it will do loop wait and check. Now I need to rerun from specify activity or rerun from failed activity. Usually for other activities then it will then skipped, but in the Until it will wait the same number of loop as previous run before exist. How could I skip this whole until and just go next? Or skip the wait in the until?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is no direct way to skip wait/until activity when you rerun the pipeline from monitor section.

To work around the issue, you may create a pipeline parameter, such as "paramSkipWait" or "paramSkipUntil", with a default value of 'N'. This parameter can be used to set the condition in an If Condition activity, which will determine the flow of the pipeline.

If the condition evaluates to true (for param value 'N'), the Until activity will not be skipped. If the condition evaluates to false, the Until activity will be skipped and the pipeline will proceed with the next flow of activities.

You can update the value of the "paramSkipUntil" parameter when you rerun the pipeline to control whether the Until activity should be skipped or not.

[image]

Please feel free to upvote/comment on below feature request regarding the same use case scenario:

[Support skip wait activity when rerunning from failed activity/selected activity](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/cd0176b9-d676-ed11-a81b-000d3adb7ffd)

[Skip successful pipeline activities when rerunning if said pipeline has not changed](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/a15671bb-3a54-ed11-a81b-000d3adfeb99)